# Where is 'Android' button in Processing?

Tags: android, processing, virtual-reality

I'm creating a VR app for my task of my University using Processing now. I googled about 'processing VR android' and finally I found this site [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTj07.png).

Then I tried to follow this work, but I couldn't find the button of 'Android'
[(second image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9cRh.png)

When I tried to play code of ' import processing.vr.*', I got a 'The package "processing.vr" does not exist.' message.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not going to go into details, but here's a short "how to" which should help you reach the point you're aiming for:

1. Click here

   [image: Click here]
2. Add this (there will be downloads and you'll have to accept terms and license)

   [image: Add this]
3. This option is now available (it wasn't before)

   [image: New option!]
4. In Android mode you can now use the option you wanted:

   [image: VR is available in android mode]

Hope it helps. Have fun!